# How to get the constant string length without making a system call?

Tags: c#, optimization, cil

A sample code:

```cs
const string UtcTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ";
public byte[] UtcTimeAscii => Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(UtcTimeFormat));
```

Here's what I got as IL for `Length` property: (Using `Microscope` VS add in)
[image]

Now: why is there a system call instead of just plain `24`?
It's a constant string. Is there a way to tell the compiler it's known ahead-of-time?

I know, I can define `24` as `const int`, but it's not right, because there would be no direct binding between the actual string and its length. Of course I can call `Length()` but I'm just curious, maybe is there a special syntax to use that kind of optimization?

I also switched the configuration from `Debug` to `Release` but the system call remained.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but `Length` is a method (well, it's a property, which in C# are implemented as methods under-the-hood as you can see in the IL). Therefore, the compiler can't know at compile-time that the `Length` property doesn't have side-effects (e.g. maybe it formats the hard drive). Therefore, it has to call it (although the JITter might be able to optimise it)

Comment: Sidenote but if this is for actual optimization, it's off the charts - if you're optimizing at this level, I expect some form of embedded systems

Comment: Remember you're looking at the *IL*. *Intermediate*. You're not seeing what code will actually run, I'm not sure what optimisations the JIT could make here.

Comment: But here's a [solid hint](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,951): "The actually code generated for this will be one instruction and will be inlined"

Comment: In what scenario is accessing the `Length` property is a bottleneck for you? I often cache the length in a local variable if it is used in a `for` but I'm not even sure that the JIT compiler would not do the same optimization. (Edit: nevermind, Damien has just commented the answer in the same moment)

Comment: I was not asking if in a particular case optimization is needed. I was asking if the C# compiler does it, and if not - how can I enable it. And yes, I plan to do some optimizations to the completed project that will be run on Raspbery Pi 4, Linux. I realize that sort of things does nothing to the power consumption, but it's "nice to know anyway". This sits in "hearbeat" function, so it will be called a lot, so the less operations the better. Final product must be readable, efficient and small. In this order.

Comment: @Harry if you use Mono to run .NET apps on Linux (instead of .NET Core), you should check the low level details yourself, because it is quite different (I cannot check that and add it to my answer because I don't have that set up)

Comment: Thanks, I will play with it while doing final tuning. The backstory is I was doing server and desktop apps so far, but I'm switching to IoT projects so I'm just doing some research about the limits of .NET Core apps. I know I will have to switch to C soon anyway. Good thing is we still have Raspbery Pi 4 for this project, so .NET is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That optimization, if it would be done, wouldn't be done by the C# compiler but rather by the JIT compiler at (well, just before) runtime. The IL is generally not indicative of what optimizations are happening, and can never prove the absence of a given optimization.

So let's look at the resulting machine code that would actually run. You can do that in the debugger, if you turn off "disable optimization on module load" (otherwise you would see intentionally unoptimized machine code), or you can use sharplab.io: [like this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIGYACMhgYQYG8aHuHIA7XBibkADAwCqGMABUAlvhgAxaPmxCAvAwBEATz064AWUNwAJqekAJSyHz4QuXADoAZm4BaWgNxcev7vQMsnxChgAUAJQc/jwBAOwSUnIKylCqGE4AMjB8AOYYABY+1LEAvjSlQA)

```
C.M()
    L0000: mov eax, 0x18
    L0005: ret
```

The result is clear: getting the length of a constant string was optimized to the constant length, no calls or even loads are involved. By the way it would not have been a *system* call in any case, it could have been a normal call to a subroutine.

Comment: when I publish the (.NET 5.0) project with `ReadyToRun` (`RTR`) option - does it get those optimizations? AFAIR this option is available for Windows only, how does it work on Linux targeted build, it's JIT only?

Comment: @Harry I don't know for sure whether this optimization would be included in the native code that comes in an R2R build, I expect it would, but even if it doesn't, a hot method would get JITted anyway so there is a second chance to get it right. And I thought R2R is also available for Linux targets, but that's not something I've ever tried to actually do.